# How can I get character-accurate identifier cross-reference for C99 code?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c99, cross-reference

I maintain several modest-sized C programs, and I frequently have a use for fully accurate cross-reference information.  Unlike "tags" or other approximations, such information is typically generated by a compiler that knows the full scoping rules of the C language and can provide accurate information accordingly.  For example, here is a snippet of information obtained from the  [`lcc`](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc/) compiler:

```
function eval src=scheme.nw:4101.0 use=scheme.nw:4101.0
  use=scheme.nw:4174.35 use=scheme.nw:4334.11 use=scheme.nw:4335.11
  use=scheme.nw:4337.11 use=scheme.nw:4340.14 use=scheme.nw:4341.4
  use=scheme.nw:4351.12 use=scheme.nw:4305.32 use=scheme.nw:4324.29
  use=scheme.nw:4278.7 use=scheme.nw:4201.8 use=scheme.nw:4234.11
  type=struct Value function(pointer to struct Exp,pointer to incomplete
  struct Env defined at scheme.nw:3889) sclass=auto scope=GLOBAL flags=0
  ref=3.710000 ncalls=46
```

This tells me that function `eval` is define in source file `scheme.nw`, line 4101, column 0, and it lists all the places that `eval` is used as well.

My problem: `lcc` works only for ANSI C, and most of my projects are migrating to C99.  **What compiler or tool will provide fully accurate cross-reference information for C99 programs?**

Linux support is a must; free software would be nice but is not absolutely required.

Answer (score 3):

The [Clang index library](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/libIndex.html#indextest) seems like a pretty decent candidate. I haven't done serious conformance testing on it personally, but [they claim](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) that the only missing C99 features are the floating point pragmas (which shouldn't affect cross-reference generation).

Comment: Looks useful, but bloody complicated.  Will take a while to evaluate.  Thanks for the pointer. +1